# How to intstall podman on SLES 12

Tags: suse, podman, sles

I tried to install podman on SLES 12 straightforwardly, but it looks like the package is missing.

```
dmitry@sles12:~> sudo zypper in podman
Refreshing service 'Advanced_Systems_Management_Module_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Containers_Module_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Legacy_Module_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Public_Cloud_Module_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Web_and_Scripting_Module_x86_64'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'podman' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'podman' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

The only piece of information I found about running podman on SLES 12 is

> SLES 12 is a bad platform to play with current container technology.
> It's too old for that and build/based around docker, not podman.

source: https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-kubic/2019-10/msg00009.html

As far as I know SLES 12 is still supported.
I checked the latest release notes of [SLES 12 SP4](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP4/) and [SLES 12 SP5](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP5/), these two were released after the first public release of podman, but there is no any mention of podman.

Answer (score 0):

Podman is not officially provided for SLE-11.

Please have a look at the release notes of SLES 15 SP2 ("5.2.1 Support for podman"):

> Starting with SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2, podman is a supported container engine. However, certain features of podman are currently not supported: [...]

Source: https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/15-SP2/#jsc-SLE-9112

You could try an **unsupported version** of podman by using the package from the community-based *Virtualization:containers* repository:

https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/Virtualization%3Acontainers/podman

Exemplary procedure:

```
zypper ar --refresh https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/containers/SLE_12_SP5/Virtualization:containers.repo
zypper ref
zypper in podman
```

You'd surely need to accept/trust the repo's signing details during the procedure and eventually you're going to need to install additional dependencies from other repositories as well.

Moving to SLES 15 SP2 might be the easier way to go.